# how to change .do in struts 1 to .html for 1 action

Tags: java, struts-1

Ex：when I click button submit, I will　go to

> ../showMemberList.do

Now I want to go action ShowMemberListAction but url change to

> ../showMemberList.html

Plz help me!

Answer (score 0):

Struts Framework by default appends `.do` extension.

You need to modify the action value as `action="actionsomthing.html"` for your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

In web.xml as below  All action will be has  .do

> > ```
> >     <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
> >     <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
> > </servlet-mapping>
> > ```

I want to change for only action ShowMemberListAction when click button submit to action ShowMemberListAction, this action will process something and return .jsp file. this time, url will

> ../showMemberList.html